# Does any version of maven-shade-plugin work with Maven 2.2.1?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a project that uses maven-shade-plugin 2.1 and I have to put it on our build server, which for some reason is still running Maven 2.2.1.

When I run the build on the (Jenkins) build server, I get this polite message:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin': 
       Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any version of the shade plugin that runs with Maven 2.2.1 or am I stuck redoing my project with the assembly plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven 3 was released in October 2010, and the shade plugin exists since November 2007, so a version of the shade plugin released before October 2010 would work with maven 2, here is a list of [all versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3a%22maven-shade-plugin%22) of the plugin in maven central.

A better solution would be to contact someone from the software factory team to check why is maven 2 being used to build your project.

They would be able to set your project to be built with the correct maven version, or give you the jenkins access needed for you to make that change.

Comment: The version 1.3.3 of maven-shade-plugin seems to work with maven 2.2.1.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**maven-shade-plugin : 1.7.1**

Adding to Angular University's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824257/4212710), the last version to work seems to be version 1.7.1, released 27-Jun-2012.

You can see from the plugin pom, the maven prerequisite version.

```
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>
```

For 1.7.1, this is `<mavenVersion>2.0.6</mavenVersion>`.

From 2.0 onwards, this becomes `<mavenVersion>3.0</mavenVersion>`.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven.plugins%7Cmaven-shade-plugin%7C1.7.1%7Cmaven-plugin